# How to invoke generic method with Action<T> parameter using reflection in C#

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I want this code to be called generic.

```
services.AddDbContext<ProductsDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
        sqlServerOptions =>
        {
            sqlServerOptions.MigrationsAssembly("Modules.Products");
        });
});
```

It's from entityframeworkcore. See the [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.entityframeworkservicecollectionextensions.adddbcontext?view=efcore-3.1#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions_AddDbContext__1_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_System_Action_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbContextOptionsBuilder__Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceLifetime_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceLifetime_).

I created a class for getting the builder:

```
public static class DbContextExtensions
{
    public static Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder> GetDbContextOptionsBuilder(string connectionString, AssemblyName moduleName)
    {
        return options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                sqlServerOptions =>
                {
                    sqlServerOptions.MigrationsAssembly(moduleName.Name);
                });
        };
    }
}
```

And I created the following for invoke the method:

```
var moduleAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(manifest);
var moduleName = moduleAssembly.GetName();

// Get dbcontext like ProductsDbContext
var dbContext = moduleAssembly.GetTypes().Where(p => typeof(DbContext).IsAssignableFrom(p)).First();

// Get the correct extensionmethod with Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder>
MethodInfo addDbContextMethod = typeof(EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions)
    .GetMethod(nameof(EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.AddDbContext),
        1,
        new Type[] { typeof(ServiceCollection), typeof(Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder>), typeof(ServiceLifetime), typeof(ServiceLifetime) });
MethodInfo generic = addDbContextMethod.MakeGenericMethod(dbContext);


// But how to pass the Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder> method?
// I tried the following but i'm lost...
var delegateType = typeof(Action<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(DbContextOptionsBuilder));
var methodInfo = typeof(DbContextExtensions).GetMethod(nameof(DbContextExtensions.GetDbContextOptionsBuilder));
var del = Delegate.CreateDelegate(delegateType, null, methodInfo);

// invoke subscribe method
generic.Invoke(services, new[] { del });
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Is your question "how to make `GetDbContextOptionsBuilder` generic and call it with a given type via reflection to get result?" For some reason I can't figure out where you are stuck...

Comment: Sorry that it's unclear. I want to call the `services.AddDbContext<ProductsDbContext>` method multiple times were the context is queried through reflection. So I loop through the assemblies and, search the context and add the context with the correct options. I only can't get it working. Don't know how to deal with the Action<T> parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code I see that `DbContextExtensions` is your local class which you don't need to call using Reflection, so you can call the `GetDbContextOptionsBuilder` method directly providing the correct parameters and get the action. Then you can call your `generic` method with the generated actions.

```
        var moduleAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(manifest);            
        var moduleName = moduleAssembly.GetName();
        var dbContext = moduleAssembly.GetTypes().Where(p => typeof(DbContext).IsAssignableFrom(p)).First();


        MethodInfo addDbContextMethod = typeof(EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions)
            .GetMethod(nameof(EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.AddDbContext),
                1,
                new Type[] { typeof(IServiceCollection), typeof(Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder>), typeof(ServiceLifetime), typeof(ServiceLifetime) });

        MethodInfo generic = addDbContextMethod.MakeGenericMethod(dbContext);

        var action = DbContextExtensions.GetDbContextOptionsBuilder("connectionString", moduleName);

        generic.Invoke(null, new object[] { services, action, ServiceLifetime.Scoped, ServiceLifetime.Scoped });
```

If you want to get the action from the external assembly, you can use the same approach by dynamically getting the `GetDbContextOptionsBuilder` method info and calling it with parameters and as the result you get the action which you can use in calling your `generic` method.

Comment: Not behind a computer right now... But if this is the answer then I was really close. Thinking to difficult I guess. I don't really understand what the `null` is as first parameter in the `generic.Invoke` method. Can you explain that part?

Comment: `AddDbContext` is an extension method so how does the invoke "know" that it must be executed on `services`?

Comment: The extension method is static so it cannot access an object instance. the Invoke first argument is object instance on which you invoke a method. For static methods it is not relevant. The services is the first argument for the method (though it is prefixed with `this` but it is only give compiler to know how to apply this method as extension). So, you just put services as ordinary argument of the method.

Comment: Works great! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Use this for inline options declaration:

```C#
Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder> options = options =>
                    {
                        options.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                            sqlServerOptions =>
                            {
                                sqlServerOptions.MigrationsAssembly(moduleName.Name);
                            });
                    };
```